# Circular dependency of defining APIGateway, ARecord, and Certificate

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

In CDK, I would like to define:

- An APIGateway (backed by a Lambda)
- An ARecord to resolve to the APIGateway
- A Certificate associated with the ARecord

The code to do this would look something like:

```
let apig = new LambdaRestApi(this, 'api', {
    handler: <some Lambda Function>,
    proxy: true,
    deploy: true,
    domainName: {
        domainName: aRecord.domainName,
        certificate: cert
    }
})

let aRecord = new ARecord(this, 'apiDNS', {
    zone: zone,
    recordName: props.recordName,
    target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new ApiGateway(apig))
})

let cert = new Certificate(this, 'cert', {
    domainName: aRecord.domainName,
    validation: CertificateValidation.fromDns(zone)
});
```

However, this appears to be impossible because of circular dependencies:

- The APIGateway needs to have a domain name set at construction-time (there's an `.addDomainName` method, but even when that is called, I still get an error `API does not define a default domain name` when trying to call `RecordTarget.fromAlias(...)`), which requires that both the Certificate and the ARecord exist.
- The ARecord needs to have a `target`, which requires that the ApiGateway exists.
- The Certificate needs to have a `DomainName` set, which requires that the ARecord exists

I guess I could manually determine what the ARecord's domainName would be, and set that as the `domainName` for the Certificate and the APIGateway - but that feels like I'm doing something wrong. Is there a way to "lazily" set the APIGateway's domainName to "the domainName of the ARecord (that hasn't been created yet)?", or some other way to achieve this setup with explicit (rather than implicit) associations?

Comment: Creating a ACM certificate doesn't need A record to be present, we just need a domain right? we can first create a certificate and pass that certificate Arn and domain to LambdaRestApi.domainName?

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in ticket, it is not possible for CDK or CloudFormation to create resource which depends on each other.

[Here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/infrastructure-and-automation/handling-circular-dependency-errors-in-aws-cloudformation/) is blog on Circular Dependency

> Resource A is dependent on Resource B, and Resource B is dependent on
> Resource A. When AWS CloudFormation assesses that this type of
> condition exists, you will get a circular dependency error because AWS
> CloudFormation is unable to clearly determine which resource should be
> created first.

In this case, we can create a ACM Certificate for subDomain and then pass the domain and certificate to LambdaRestApi.

Here is the modified CDK.

```
const rootDomain = "mydomain.com";
const subDomain = "api-test";

const zone = route53.HostedZone.fromLookup(this, "baseZone", {
  domainName: rootDomain,
});

let cert = new acm.Certificate(this, "cert", {
  domainName: `${subDomain}.${rootDomain}`,
  validation: acm.CertificateValidation.fromDns(zone),
});

const backend = new lambda.Function(this, "MyLayeredLambda", {
  code: new lambda.InlineCode("foo"),
  handler: "index.handler",
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
});

const restApi = new apigw.LambdaRestApi(this, "myapi", {
  handler: backend,
  domainName: {
    domainName: `${subDomain}.${rootDomain}`,
    certificate: cert,
    endpointType: apigw.EndpointType.REGIONAL,
  },
});

new route53.ARecord(this, "apiDNS", {
  zone: zone,
  recordName: `${subDomain}`,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(
    new route53Targets.ApiGateway(restApi)
  ),
});
}
```

Comment: Right - this is basically doing what I described in the final paragraph - manually determining what the domain _would_ be (`${subDomain}.${rootDoman}`), and then passing that around, rather than directly referencing the ARecord's domain. The two values _happen_ to be the same - but it feels weird that I can't directly reference one from the other.

Comment: Correct. CloudFormation template behind the scenes will fail to determine which resource to create first as one depends on other.

Comment: Also updated answer with a blog to circular dependency.